# MongoDB Aggregation: How to check if an object containing multiple properties exists in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an array of objects and I want to check if there is an object that matches multiple properties. I have tried using `$in` and `$and` but it does not work the way I want it to.

[Here is my current implementation.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dEQp2Q4DW0j)

I have an array like

```
"choices": [
    {
        "name": "choiceA",
        "id": 0,
        "l": "k"
    },
    {
        "name": "choiceB",
        "id": 1,
        "l": "j"
    },
    {
        "name": "choiceC",
        "id": 2,
        "l": "l"
    }
]
```

I am trying to write aggregation code that can check if there is an object that contains both `"id":2` and `"l":"j"` properties. My current implementation checks if there is an object containing the first property then checks if there is an object containing the second one.

How can I get my desired results?

Below, see my aggregation query. The full code is [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dEQp2Q4DW0j)

```
db.poll.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 100
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      numberOfVotes: {
        $and: [
          {
            $in: [
              2,
              "$choices.id"
            ]
          },
          {
            $in: [
              "j",
              "$choices.l"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

The above query returns true yet there is no object in the array both of the properties `id:2` and `"l":"J"`. I know the code works as expected. How can I get my desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use something like [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

```
db.collection.find({
  choices: {
    $elemMatch: {
      id: 2,
      l: "j"
    }
  }
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6CAU8EPntmT)

---

EDIT

In an aggregation `$project` stage I would use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

```
db.poll.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 100
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      numberOfVotes: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$choices",
                as: "choice",
                cond: {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$choice.id",
                        2
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$choice.l",
                        "j"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G26ZnCLOA8z)

Comment: I updated the title to be more clear. I want to check if an object containing two specific properties exists in an array. I know how to do it with one property. I use `$in`. But how can I do it with two properties?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand, is `choices: [{id: 2, l: "k"}, {id: 3, l:"j"}]` a matching document?

Comment: No. In the question I have a link to the aggregation query that shows what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: i edited my answer that to match the pipeline you use, as you cant use `$elemMatch` in an aggregation project stage I would use `$filter` instead.